# Problem with installing sqlite browser

Tags: sqlite

Unfortunately I am unable to install sqlite browser. The issue that pops up is :"Unable to install sqlite browser: no snap revision on specified channel".

Can anyone help me with proceeding?

Cheers,
Noah

Comment: It is an application, not sure if snap version available or not as snaps tend to be too isolated. Did you run `sudo apt install sqlite3` ?

Answer (score 1):

So I'm new to linux so no guarantees, and correct me if I'm wrong, but...

Seems that you need to install through a different channel. If you use this in terminal:

```
sudo snap install <program-name>
```

it should give back the error "snap 'program-name' is not available on stable" and proceed to name the channels it IS available on, as well as the command to use.

(I used this on 2 different programs already, one of them had to be installed with --beta, the other through --edge. Both worked out fine.)

Answer (score 1):

To install the latest stable sqlitebrowser snap package open the terminal and type:

```
sudo snap install sqlitebrowser
```

The sqlitebrowser snap package currently has one other version on the edge channel (latest/edge). No unique candidate and beta channel sqlitebrowser versions are currently available. To install the latest edge sqlitebrowser snap package run the following command:

```
sudo snap install sqlitebrowser --channel=latest/edge
```